# List all posts with the parent or grandparent of a page with a specified ID

Tags: pages, child-pages, get-children

I am using the following code in a page template

```
<?php
   $args=array(
    'post_parent' => 27641,
     'post_type' => 'page',
   );
   $my_query = null;
   $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
   if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {

   while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
```

to get a list of direct child pages for a product listing page.

What do I do if I want all child pages and all grandchildren too? I want to list the children of child pages as well as the direct children.

The obvious answer would be:

```
'post_ancestor' => 27641,
```

or

```
'post_grandparent' => 27641,
```

but unfotunately it's not that simple.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `get_pages( array( 'child_of' => page_id ) )` to get all sub-pages.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I'm not sure what to do with that.

Comment: Basically this function allows you to grab all children and children of children and so on.
You can find more information in [WP Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages).

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Tomasz answers the question, but for those who are Googling this, here's a little more information on `get_pages()`.

**NOTE:** I would skip the `WP_Query`, unless you want to directly modify and alter the main query and for this example/question, you really don't need the `$args`

```
// Gets the global post variable.    
global $post;

// Get all the ancestors of page id 27641
$pages = get_pages( array( 'child_of' => 27641 ) );

// Using $post because setup_postdata requires a reference to the global $post
// Loop through each post object in $pages
foreach ( $pages as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
// this is your loop. Because we setup_postdata, we can use loop functions like the_title, the_content, etc.
        <li>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </li>
// This ends the loop
    <?php endforeach; 
// Reset the postdata and continue with your page.
    wp_reset_postdata();
```